# How can I open page after some period of time (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have two pages of type PhoneApplicationPage. After I open Main Page, how can I open the next page after 4 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call it from constructor:

```
DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)
};
Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    Timer.Stop();
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SecondPage.xaml"));        
};
Timer.Start();
```

Comment: Make sure to stop the timer in OnNavigatingFrom to prevent it from firing if the user presses the back or home buttons (or you'll get an InvalidOperationException)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), this class can be configured to raise an event after a certain period of time. Within the event handler, perform your navigation via the NavigationService.